# Resetting Mockito Spy

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a test class (based on TestNG) where I use `Mockito.verify` for a spy object.

This works:

```
public class Program {
    @Spy
    private TestObject testObject;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       testObject.makeSth(); 
       verify(testObject, only()).someMethodNeedToBeChecked(); 
    }
}
```

But here:

```
public class Program {
    @Spy
    private TestObject testObject;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       testObject.makeSth(); 
       verify(testObject, only()).someMethodNeedToBeChecked(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // Some different scenario
       testObject.makeSth(); 
       verify(testObject, only()).someMethodNeedToBeChecked(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

I get a Mokito exception that I have more that one invocation of `someMethodNeedToBeChecked` method. Of course I tried to add `Mockito.reset(testObject)` but it didn't help me at all.

How can I reset a spy object if I need to verify the same method in several tests?

Comment: I asked a similar question over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188299/is-this-an-appropriate-use-of-mockitos-reset-method. Just FYI, although that related to a mock not a spy.

Comment: Where did you attempt to add the call to `reset`? Maybe edit your code to show your attempt, but commented out?

Comment: I attached just prototype example, reset I tried to make in @BeforeMethod\@BeforeClass, the same with @After, even before verification - it didn't work. As I understand it's an issue just with spies and reset is just for mock objects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Mockito [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) :

> Resetting mocks (Since 1.8.0)
>
> Smart Mockito users hardly use this feature because they know it could be a sign of poor tests. Normally, you don't need to reset your mocks, just create new mocks for each test method.
>   Instead of reset() please consider writing simple, small and focused test methods over lengthy, over-specified tests. First potential code smell is reset() in the middle of the test method. This probably means you're testing too much. Follow the whisper of your test methods: "Please keep us small & focused on single behavior". There are several threads about it on mockito mailing list.
>
> The only reason we added reset() method is to make it possible to work with container-injected mocks.

You should probably just recreate the spy in a `@BeforeMethod` :

```
public class Program {

    private TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
    private TestObject spyTestObject;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void buildSpy() {
        spyTestObject = spy(testObject);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       spyTestObject.makeSth(); 
       verify(spyTestObject , only()).someMethodNeedToBeChecked(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // Some different scenario
       spyTestObject.makeSth(); 
       verify(spyTestObject , only()).someMethodNeedToBeChecked(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying that each test will now need to expect two invocations. The spy is rebuild before each test method.

Comment: Thanks, actually it helped me, but if you use anotations like @InjectMocks and others you need also to call there initmocks that seems not so beauty.

Comment: So I have to have a different field for every test if I use @ Spy? that seems ugly, and makes @ Spy rather pointless except in very trivial cases, and trappy in test classes with more than one test method. I just spend 30 min discovering that because of the @ Spy not getting reset between tests, the run order of my tests effects the outcome. There must be someway to reset a spy in @ AfterTests or at the start of @ BeforeTests?

Comment: You can reset the spy in a method annotated with @ BeforeMethod (Or @ Before with JUnit) just like I did in my example, what's the problem?